Google Authentication Not Appearing in Django Project
I am trying to set up Google authentication in my Django project using django-allauth, but the Google login option is not appearing on my login page. I suspect I might be missing a configuration step or setting.
I have confirmed the site ID is correct by checking the link: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sites/site/3/change/
Could someone help me identify what I might be missing or doing wrong?
django version : 3.2
django-allauth : version: 0.62.1
Here are the relevant parts of my settings.py:
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "google": {
        "app": [
            {
                "client_id": "myid",
                "secret": "mysecret",
            },
        ],
        "SCOPE": [
            "profile",
            "email",
        ],
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {
            "access_type": "online",
        },
    }
}


SITE_ID = 3

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware',

    'livereload.middleware.LiveReloadScript',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'core.views.site_settings',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware',

    'livereload.middleware.LiveReloadScript',
]


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'  # Redirect after login
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'  # Redirect after logout




Backwards incompatible changes
The django-allauth required dependencies are now more fine grained. If you do not use any of the social account functionality, a pip install django-allauth will, e.g., no longer pull in dependencies for handling JWT. If you are using social account functionality, install using pip install django-allauth[socialaccount]. That will install the dependencies covering most common providers. If you are using the Steam provider, install using pip install django-allauth[socialaccount,steam].
pip install django-allauth[socialaccount]

work for me .

Ensure that your settings.py file includes the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS setting:
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

For the Google authentication provider to function correctly, make sure you've installed the required dependencies: requests and jwt.
https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/release-notes/recent.html#backwards-incompatible-changes
pip install requests
pip install jwt

You can find detailed setup instructions in the official documentation.
