I have used to Google provider in social AUTH in Django, but provider is not showing in Django template
social app
I am trying to set up Google authentication in my Django project using django-allauth, but the Google login option is not appearing on my login page. I have used this code :
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
   
]`

MIDDLEWARE = [
   'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware',
]
SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/'
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        },

    }
}


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78415653/google-authentication-not-appearing-in-django-project Now It's work. I have follow this link

Your problem  maybe cause by Backwards incompatible changes.
ask the docs say , if you do not use any of the social account functionality, a pip install django-allauth will, e.g., no longer pull in dependencies for handling JWT.
Use
pip install django-allauth[socialaccount]


